# NPM package organized into modules

Tags: typescript, npm, module, package

I would like to create an NPM package so that imports are divided into modules.

Now, when I use my NPM package in other projects, the import looks like this:

```
import { myFunction1, myFunction2 } from 'my-package';
```

I would like this to be divided into modules like this:

```
import { myFunction1 } from 'my-package/products';
import { myFunction2 } from 'my-package/sales';
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf ./dist && tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

**src/index.ts**

```
export { myFunction1 } from './products';
export { myFunction2 } from './sales';
```

I appreciate everyone's help in advance.
Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead, research how to achieve it with npm and implement it. If you are stuck with a specific problem or error, you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible with an entry in the package.json file called exports:

```json
"exports": {
  "./server": "./lib/server",
  "./react": "./lib/react"
},
```

Add also corresponding declaration files

*react.d.ts*

```
export * from "./lib/react";
```

*server.d.ts*

```
export * from "./lib/server";
```

You can read more about it here: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points

Comment: Unfortunately, following your answer, this doesn't work.